# Powershell Script to get details of user along with group they are member of

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to export AD user list along with the group they are member of, exported csv format should be like

Group A User1_name
Group A User2_name
Group B User3_name
Group C User4_name
Group C User5_name

I have tried

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"  
Get-Content R:\PHRBI-R\ADGroup_list.csv | Where{$_ -ne $null -and $_.trim() -ne ""} |   
    foreach{  
        $Group = $_   
        Write-Host "$Group"  
        Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties members |  
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty members |  
            Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname, enabled |  
            Select samaccountname, name, Enabled  
    }
```

But it doesn't gave the template I'm looking for and also new group keep adding so can't list groups manually in any file and export the required details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should get you going, I tried to make it logical to follow. This can, of course, be cleaned up and optimized.

```
# Create csv
New-Item "Some\Path\To\CSV" -ItemType File -force

# Add header row
Add-Content -Path "Some\Path\To\CSV" -Value 'Group Name, NUID, Name, Enabled'

# Loop through each AD group
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like 'ABC*'} | Foreach-Object {
    # Keep the group object so we can use it later
    $Group = $_
    
    # loop through each group  member
    $Group.members | Foreach-Object {
        $User = Get-ADUser -identity $_ -Properties samaccountname, name, enabled

        Add-Content -Path "Some\Path\To\CSV" -Value "$($Group.Name),$($User.samaccountname),$($User.name),$($User.Enabled)"
    }
}
```

Note that If there are nested groups (i.e. groups within groups) then the `Get-AdUser` cmdlet will error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more thing when I'm trying to export it to csv adding an extra line ("| Out-File R:\PHRBI-R\Unlicensed_User\file2.csv"), data gets exported in a single column how can we separate it like group name in one column and user name in another

Comment: Also how can I pass group members dynamically  instead of passing a text file containing group list

Comment: You can just use the inner part of the ```foreach``` loop and remove the ```-Identity $Group``` part. As for the csv part, just add a comma after the Group variable, so ```"$Group,```

Comment: I have tried a different approach and was able to extract the details with the template I require, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Ask a question > someone answers it (gets accepted) > ask for extra requirements > no response > un-accepts answer and accepts own answer. Feels just like an actual job haha!

Comment: I didn't notice that your answer got unselected, i selected it as an answer now as what i asked initially it reallly gave me that output.

Comment: no worries! I have changed the code to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

New-Item R:\PHRBI-R\Nishant\AD_List\user_list.csv -ItemType File -force

Add-Content -Path R:\PHRBI-R\Nishant\AD_List\user_list.csv -Value 'Group Name, NUID, Name,Enabled'

$Groups=Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like 'ABC*'}  

foreach($Group in $Groups)

{
$Details=Get-ADGroup  -Identity $Group.Name -Properties members |

Select-Object -ExpandProperty members |

Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname, enabled, name  | Select samaccountname, name, Enabled

foreach($Detail in $Details)

{
Add-Content -Path R:\PHRBI-R\Nishant\AD_List\user_list.csv -Value "$($Group.Name),$($Detail.samaccountname),$($Detail.name),$($Detail.Enabled)"
 }}
```